# Why does Thinking Sphinx refuse to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to implement a simple search with Thinking Sphinx, but, it doesnt work. I'm going through "[A Quick Guide to Getting Setup with Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/quickstart.html)", and when I try to use `rake ts:index` I get a nasty error:

```
Generating configuration to /Users/Kuba/Desktop/Rails/black/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/Users/Kuba/Desktop/Rails/black/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'news_post_core'...
ERROR: index 'news_post_core': sql_connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2) (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:3306/black1).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

I have no idea, what to do with it. My only index is:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :news_post, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title
end
```

My database.yml is:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: black1
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: black1
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: black1
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

I installed MySQL from the package downloaded from the Oracle website.

The system I'm on is Mountain Lion. I definitely have MySQL server running, it's easy to check in system preferences.

Also, I installed Sphinx through Macports.
What might be possible solutions to this?

Comment: I'm presuming your Rails app has no issues connecting to your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing Sphinx didn't correctly link up with MySQL when you installed it via macports (I generally would recommend homebrew over macports these days).

What happens if you specify a host of 127.0.0.1 in your database.yml file for the appropriate environments? That might convince Sphinx to connect via TCP instead of file sockets.

(Also: are you really using the same database for both development and test environments?)

Comment: i added 'host: 127.0.0.1' and i think it actually works... you cant possibly be aware of how shocked i am at this moment, fighting with this crap for hours right now